# Can I get coloured output in interactive python shell?

Tags: command-line, python

When I open a python shell with `python`, can I have a colored output? For example red errors like you are used from IDEs?

```
>>> 10 * (1/0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  FIle "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

I both read `man python` and `python --help`, but didn't find anything regarding colours so I assume that there is nothing by default, but is it achievable anyway?

Comment: BTW: Of course I didn't require a syntax highlightning like in the example above. askubuntu colored it like that. (I don't think colour in std.in is possible)

Comment: Colouring your *input* is possible depending on the application. For example, [the `zsh` and `fish` shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105030/70524) support it. But Python's shells don't provide any mechanism I know of, which supports it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) for an enhanced Python interactive shell.

```
sudo apt-get install ipython     # Python 2
sudo apt-get install ipython3    # Python 3
```

For example:

[image]

IPython has other useful features, such as a browser-based interface.

Comment: Ok, that's a nice tool. Especially the repetiton of the whole command with the arrow-keys since I am a beginner with python...

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Were you using `python2`? `python3`'s shell has the arrow-key-history feature.

Comment: Yes I have python2. In the normal shell (`python`) I can repeat only 1 line, never a whole command over multiple lines such as a loop